# Create a XLSX file inside an PPT file

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint, vsto, powerpoint-addins

I am working on a Powerpoint addon which I need to save meta into an EXCEL file. And I don't want to create to separate file and link it. I am using `c#` with `VSTO` for my addon.

I wanted to create an EXCEL file inside a PPT file. Is that possible? If yes Can anyone guide me through it?

Comment: Any PPT presentation, slide within a presentation, shape on a slide can have any number of tags in its .Tags collection. Commonly these tags contain string values of any length. You could conceivably store CSV data in one of these and somehow convert it to XL format on the fly as needed. But there are also tags that support Binary data; I haven't used them myself, but that would seem to be the natural solution.

Comment: What is your end goal of embedding an excel file inside a presentation?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Just wanted to store some N number of chart data into a single file. Then just link this file to those charts.